# How to reserve a processor in Windows Server for Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rdp

Windows Server 2012 R2, every once in a while a runaway process will take up all the CPU and my RDP session will either take forever to start or disconnect after a long wait.  Is there a way to reserve a CPU so that I never have an issue Remoting into the server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Server 2016 rds cpu usage per user low](https://serverfault.com/questions/905016/windows-server-2016-rds-cpu-usage-per-user-low)

Comment: No, that is referring to the use of CPU of the RDS user, what I am looking to do is reserve CPU time for an RDS user in case another processor decides to run wild and someone needs to login and kill it.